# Android, Отправка изображения на сервер

Tags: android, сервер, изображения, post, загрузка

Перелопатил уже с десяток библиотек multipartEntity, ничего не выходит, то библиотеки несовместимы то еще что-то, может руки кривые. Подскажите пожалуйста варианты загрузки изображения на сервер в Post запросе без multipartEntity, если такое возможно

Comment: Зависит еще от того как сервер принимает.

Comment: @cpp-user, затрудняюсь ответить на этот вопрос. Но при помощи POSTMAN отправляется как пара "key - file"  и тип form-data

Comment: Без multipartEntity это нужно менять протокол как минимум на TCPIP, если нужен именно HTTP здесь конечно без multipartEntity не обойтись и заюзать либо сURL либо на Java через HttpClient + HttpPost.

Comment: @cpp-user,понял спасибо, будем дальше "копать" библиотеки!)